# Wamp icon is green but not reacting on click

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm facing with the problem where my fresh installed WAMP 3.0 is running, icon is green, apache and MYSQL are up and running, localhost page is accessible but if I click on my WAMP icon to change any of the settings icon is not reacting at all. Either left  or right mouse click are not working. Even if I want to shutdown WAMP I have to do that over Task manager. 
WAMP is running on Win7 x64 machine. Previous version of WAMP 2.2 has been working.
I have tried uninstalling and installing again all Microsoft C++ packages but still no success.

[List of installed C++ packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36MPb.jpg)

Not sure what can go wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the 32bit AND 64bit MSVC Runtimes installed. The wampmanager.exe is still a 32bit application even on a 64bit windows. In [this document](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) on the WAMPServer forum, there are links to the microsoft download pages for all these runtimes

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I tried everything and I followed all links from WAMPServer forum. Tried several times with uninstalling everything and fresh installations again but without any success.

Comment: Go to [this page its a backup download site for WAMPServer](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=english). There is a tool on there called `Checks VC++ packages installed` Download that and install it, it does nothing other than check and report any missing MSVC runtimes

Comment: "All VC++ packages needed to Wampserver seem to be installed correctly." I did reinstall Wampserver after one more time, but still I'm having same problem. Icon is green and server is running but I don't have any options on mouse click over icon.

Comment: Does it show a tooltip when you hover over the WAMPServer icon in the system tray?

Comment: Yes, and it says "All services running - server offline"

Comment: And a left click over wampmanager in the system tray does not show you a menu?

Comment: No, no response either with left or right click.

Comment: Post a message on http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2 I can offer you a TeamViewer session from there. We can look at this together then. If thats OK with you

Comment: It is posted on Wamp forum as well. After we conclude what is a problem we will post solution here so all other users can see it.

Comment: we've tried to resolve this, but without any success. we just can't figure out whats wrong with windows and maybe some components.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click [this link](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/visual-c-redistributable-runtime-package-all-in-one/).
2. After clicking on the link, you'll see "Visual C++ Redistributable Runtimes All-in-One July 2021".
3. Click on download button
4. Choose the closest server option
5. Wait to download it.
6. Extract the download folder at any location you want.
7. Open the extracted folder.
8. Click on the "install_all" file and  download it.
9. Then one by one  click on rest applications and then click on the repair radio button .& do this for all remaining applications.
10. Some applications may ask you to restart your system, then restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same situation. The problem was the installation of wamp was not proper. First I downloaded the msvcr100.dll past it at the "C:\Windows\System32" then complete the installation and wamp icon become green but right mouse click did not work. Then I download msvcr110.dll past it at the same location "C:\Windows\System32". After that, I uninstall the wamp completely and install it again now everything is working properly and right-click on wamp icon is also working.

Answer (score 0):

For others coming here with that tray icon/menu not responding to clicks, check if the partition you installed WAMP on is NTFS.  **WampServer DOES NOT fully work on a FAT32 or exFAT partition**, it only works fine on NTFS!  Apache and PHP seem to work just fine on exFAT but not the Aestan Tray Menu thingy that WAMP ships with.

Answer (score 0):

When you run Wamp you should see pop-up to list some missing staff you should download them and put them in System32

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue like you. With me, the root cause is I did not install enough VC redistribute, you can check for yourself by using tool http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe.
Anyways, I've just downloaded from http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ in section Visual C++ Redistribuable Packages (https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/vcpackages/all_vc_redist_x86_x64.zip) and run all of them.
After that, install Wamp and enjoy it ! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Im facing similar problem. im using 32 bit device and windows 10. my way to solve unresponsive wamp icon by download & install two exe :

1. Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019,2022(it in one exe file) 64x
2. Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0) x 64

from link below https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the solutions that people say but it doesent work! then i've install the wampserver v 3.2.6.

Thats easy!
Where is khaby now :) ?