# WAMP 3.2 tray icon is green and everything works, except NOTHING happens when left/right click on it?

Tags: wamp, wampserver, system-tray

WampServer 3.2.0 (last Windows 7 compatible version I found) was installed today on an old PC using right-click "**Run as Administrator**" and no error was displayed at all, all seemed normal.  http://localhost works and reports thru index.php that everything is fine except PHP config needs to be refreshed by right-clicking WampManager > Refresh, so I was about to do that when I realized that absolutely NOTHING happens when left/right clicking the WAMP tray icon AT ALL.  No error, no nothing.  It's just a brick.

I have installed all the **required x86 and x64 MVC++ redistributables** and I have confirmed this by running check_vcredist.exe

I have tried **rebooting** and **starting Wampserver64.exe as an administrator** but it doesn't change anything.

I **uninstalled, manually removed the e:/wamp folder (my install dir) reinstalled**, but nothing fixes this aggravating issue.  It's so weird that EVERYTHING WORKS perfectly, except this stupid tray icon menu?!

Any ideas?

I've already tried:

[Wamp icon is green but not reacting on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131230/wamp-icon-is-green-but-not-reacting-on-click)

http://jcyberinux.com/rjdreyes/wampserver-eparseerror-no-tray-icon-was-specified.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the WampServer installer gives a lot of instructions, but apparently skips giving the most important one: **WampServer DOES NOT work on an exFAT partition!**

I found that extremely relevant bit of information on this random page: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-your-own-wampserver/